# Static lease IP dhcp within dynamic range pool

Tags: dhcp, fedora, dhcp-server

I am using fedora 13.

I want to statically bind a MAC to IP. Now the problem is if the IP is within the range pool, it may get allocated to some other host also. For that I use a tweak, where I insert a entry in dhcpd.leases (although not recommended). Can anyone recommend a better solution. My requirement is, if I statically bind IP to a host then no matter what, it should be assigned to that host only. It is ok if I need to update the dhcp version, only problem is that I cannot update the fedora version, due to some reasons.

I referred this this [link](https://serverfault.com/questions/299046/is-it-okay-to-set-static-ip-within-the-range-of-dhcp) but has no solution to allow static binding of IP within the range pool.

Answer (score 3):

Use a reservation as shown in [Example 10.3. Static IP address using DHCP](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/16/html/System_Administrators_Guide/s1-dhcp-configuring-server.html) to fix the address to a particular MAC.

The reserved address is not allocated to any other host requesting an address.

Comment: My problem is that if the fixed address parameter is with the range of dynamic pool then there is a chance that it might get allocated to some other host also. I want a fix for such problem.

Comment: No it won't. That is the whole point of setting the reservation is the DHCP server reserves that IP within the pool and is only allowed to assign that dynamic IP to that MAC address.

Answer (score 1):

Segment/Split your pool.

pool {

```
                range xxx.xxx.1.20 xxx.xxx.1.22;
                range xxx.xxx.1.24 xxx.xxx.1.249;
```

}

Now you have xxx.xxx.1.23 available to allocate to a static assignment.